# Searching for the measure of an angle (circle)

Tags: circles

[image]

We know that $\widehat{ACB}=75^\circ$ and that $\left(AB\right)//\left(CD\right)$.
We know that $\widehat{CDB}=35^\circ$, and $A, B, C, D$ are on a circle $C$, wich has for center $O$ (not

on the drawing).

I'm trying to get the mesure of $\widehat{DCB}$.

That's what I tried :

$\widehat{ACB}=75^\circ$ and $\widehat{ACB}=\widehat{BDA}$, so $\widehat{BDA}=75^\circ$.

Also,

$\widehat{CDB}=35^\circ$ and $\widehat{CDB}=\widehat{BAC}$, so $\widehat{BAC}=35^\circ$.

But then, I'm blocked, I don't know what else I don't know...
How can I use the point $O$ if I don't know where it is on the drawing ?
I should I do then ?

Thanks.

Comment: Fix the formatting to get rid of the "\widehat"s and maybe insert missing equal signs, if they were meant to be there. Otherwise it's hard to read your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\angle CDA = \angle CDB + \angle BDA = 35^\circ + 75^\circ = 110^\circ$ and $\angle DBA = 35^\circ$ because $CD  \parallel BA.$  in a cyclic quad $\angle CBA + \angle CDA  = 180^\circ$ so $\angle CBA = 70^\circ$ and using $\angle DBA = 35^\circ$ we have $\angle CBD = 35^\circ$  look at the isosceles   triangle $BCD$ and conclude that $\angle BCD = 110^\circ$